# Threejs image texture on a mesh is getting stretched according to the size of mesh

Tags: three.js

I have created a pre-defined area (mesh) in the GLTF file from blender where user can upload a image to see it as a logo image on the product. The pre-defined area (mesh) on the product has a specific height and width and user can upload image of any size. The problem I am facing is - When user uploads the image it get stretched  according to the mesh area size but I want it to keep the aspect ratio of image and reduce the size of image to get fit in the mesh area.

How image textured on the mesh

[image: textured]

The actual image:

[image: actual]

Expected image texture on the mesh:

[image: expected]

Following is the Threejs texture code -

```
$scope.loadTexture(textureImage).then((texture) => {
    texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    if (currentMesh.texture_rotation != undefined) {
        texture.rotation = currentMesh.texture_rotation;
    }

    texture.repeat.x = currentMesh.texture_repeat_x;
    texture.repeat.y = currentMesh.texture_repeat_y;
    texture.flipY = currentMesh.flipY;
    texture.anisotropy = currentMesh.anisotropy;
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    node.material.map = texture;
    node.material.map.minFilter = currentMesh.texture_min_filter;
    node.material.map.magFilter = currentMesh.texture_mag_filter;
    node.material.needsUpdate = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's stretching is because you're trying to apply a rectangular texture to a square(ish) area. The UVs of the square want to match the corners of the texture to the corners of the square, which is causing stretching.

The easiest option is to take the input image and draw it onto a canvas using its [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). The canvas should have the same aspect ratio as your label area. You can then use [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture) as your texture.

An alternative would be to create a new label `Mesh` that matches the aspect ratio of the incoming image. This would take more math to correctly size and position the label `Mesh`, but it may turn out nicer in the long run.

#### Finding the aspect ratio of the label

It looks like you're using a cylinder. The height of the label is given--you know how tall it is. The width of the label is the arc length of either the top or bottom edge. You can find this with three.js code, as long as you know the corner points in local space, and the radius of your cylinder.

```js
const topLeftCorner = new THREE.Vector3(/*...*/)
const topRightCorner = new THREE.Vector3(/*...*/)
const angle = topLeftCorner.angleTo( topRightCorner ) // radians
const arcLength = angle * cylinderRadius
```

All of this is in scene units, but that doesn't matter, because you're after a ratio. Because aslect ratio is `W/H`, just take your arc length divided by the label height.

```js
const labelAspectRatio = arcLength / labelHeight
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going with the easiest option. I have created the logic, it is working great but I am struggling to get the aspect ratio of label area. How can I get the aspect ratio of label area and convert it to canvas width/height so that I can create canvas accordingly? Currently, I am measuring it with chrome extension and adding in code as a static value.

Comment: @SimranjitKaur I've updated my answer with some hints on how to get the aspect ratio of the label area in your model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have multiple different products (.glb models) for example - A bus, horse, bag, cup etc. I am creating label area for each product so it can be a cylinder or a plane.

Comment: @SimranjitKaur Regardless, aspect ratio is just a ratio of width/height. A plane should be even easier to compute.

Comment: Yes @TheJim01, the problem I am facing is when when I get width and height in code using following code:
 `let box3 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);`
 `var meshWidth = box3.max.x - box3.min.x;`
 `var meshHeight = box3.max.y - box3.min.y;`
It is not giving the same height and width as it is showing in blender so I am not getting the correct aspect ratio in the calculation.

Comment: I just got the issue Box3 is giving z coordinates in y and y in z. For example - in blender it is showing `x = 2, y = 2.85 and z = 0.25` but Box3 is returning `x = 2, y = 0.25 and z = 2.85`. Could you please let me know how can I fix that?

Comment: @SimranjitKaur I'm not sure how bounding boxes in Blender work, but in three.js, they are in World coordinates. So if your label is transformed in the +Z direction by 2.6, then that would be the different you're seeing.